# Apache Metamodel - Min/Max/Default values

Tags: java, database, jdbc, metamodel, apache-metamodel

Is there a way to get to the default value for a column and/or the min/max constraints for a column using Apache Metamodel?

I know in the java.sql.DatabaseMetaData you can get to the default value of a column but I am not seeing the same accessor in the column definition for Metamodel.

I am not finding a way to get min/max values in either, so I am wondering if this is possible due to the way they are maintained.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no such functionality in Apache MetaModel.

Would be a nice addition though.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Depends on how you see it ... In my opinion it _is_ an answer to the question, but unfortunately not a resolution to the issue/concern raised.